# print custom image field for taxonomy page (page--taxonomy.html.twig) template

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms

How do I load an image from a taxonomy custom field into a custom location on the taxonomy page template?

It's easy to accomplish it when the image is in a node. The following code works for images, but it doesn't work for taxonomy pages.

```
    {{ file_url(node.field_reference_background.entity.uri.value) }}
```

How can I accomplish the same for taxonomy pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only entities from type node are loaded in the page template by default. If you want this for other entity types you have to add custom code to page preprocess:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    $term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term');
    $variables['term'] = $term;
  }
}
```

Then you can access the fields from the term in page--taxonomy.html.twig:

```
{{ file_url(term.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Comment: You are the man! That is exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks!!! ++

Comment: is there a way to also exclude the newly declared field from further output on the page? I see that if you remove it from the display it will not show further but I wonder if theres a way I can do that purely with the theme?

Comment: If you want to exclude the field in twig, then put `{{ content|without('field_name') }}` in taxonomy-term.html.twig.

Comment: Supplementary answer / another option, if you are instead using the taxonomy term twig, e.g. `taxonomy-term.html.twig` - I found this to work: `<img src="{{ file_url(term.field_image.entity.field_media_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}"/>`  where `field_image` is the field "image" added to the taxonomy term entity of type Media (an entity reference) and `field_media_image` is the field of the Media entity that the `field_image` refers to.